# Create / Alter procedure referencing non-existing table or view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> A procedure can reference tables that do not yet exist. At creation
> time, only syntax checking is performed. The procedure is not compiled
> until it is executed for the first time. Only during compilation are
> all objects referenced in the procedure resolved. Therefore, a
> syntactically correct procedure that references tables that do not
> exist can be created successfully; however, the procedure fails at
> execution time if the referenced tables do not exist.

I was always under the impression that referenced tables *are* checked.  For example if you reference an incorrect column in an existing view it complains *at compile time*:

[image]

So what is going on here, why are columns checked within the procedure but not views / tables?

Comment: A `VIEW` isn't a Stored Procedure, they are completely different objects. Also are you *really* using SQL Server 2005? That's been out of support for almost 5 years and you should be urgently looking at upgrade paths.

Comment: @Larnu sorry no I've updated the tags.  The SP is using the view within it.

Answer (score 1):

The document is referencing that, at the time to Stored Procedure is created, it isn't validated. Take this batch:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO


CREATE PROC dbo.MyProc @ID int AS
BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.MyTable 
    WHERE ID = @ID;
END;

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (ID int, 
                          SomeValue varchar(20));
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
VALUES(1,'asdjka'),
      (2,'asdkj');
GO

EXEC dbo.MyProc 1;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable;
DROP PROC dbo.MyProc;
```

Notice that I `CREATE` `dbo.MyProc` ***before*** `dbo.MyTable`, even though it references that object. That's because the validity of the objects in the procedure isn't checked at the point the procedure is created or altered.

A `VIEW` on the other hand, is checked at the time that it is created.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (ID int, 
                          SomeValue varchar(20));
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
VALUES(1,'asdjka'),
      (2,'asdkj');

GO
--Fails
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView AS

    SELECT ID,
           SomeValue,
           SomeInt
    FROM dbo.MyTable;
GO
--Fails
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyOtherView AS

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.MyOtherTable;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable;
```

Depending on the object type depends on what is validated and isn't when the DDL statement is issued.

---

Edit: It seems that what the OP is questioning is why do that get an error if the object does exist, but they reference a column that doesn't. For exmaple take the below batch:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (ID int, 
                          SomeValue varchar(20));
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
VALUES(1,'asdjka'),
      (2,'asdkj');
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.MyProc @ID int AS
BEGIN

    SELECT ID,
           SomeValue,
           AnotherValue
    FROM dbo.MyTable 
    WHERE ID = @ID;
END;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable;
GO
DROP PROC dbo.MyProc;
GO
```

This fails as the column `AnotherValue` does not exist. This is actually covered in the very documentation you quote:

> A procedure can reference tables that do not yet exist. At creation time, only syntax checking is performed.

It explicitly states you can reference a **table** that does not exist. It makes no mention of objects that don't, or (more specifically) columns in a table/object. Referencing a table that *does* exist **will** be validated at creation time.

Comment: Thanks, although I think you misunderstood slightly.  I can create a procedure, which references a view that doesn't exist.  However if that view does exist it will tell me (at compile time) I have incorrect column names.

Comment: If you are referencing an object that *does* exist then the syntax needs to be correct, @m.edmondson . The table isn't checked for existing, but if it does, you need to reference valid columns. If your `VIEW`/`TABLE` definition is changing all the time, that suggests a larger, underlying problem/

Comment: Correct I understand this is happening but why would it?  Surely either always check at compile or always check on execute, not some sort of hybrid?

Comment: You aren't referencing a table that **doesn't** exist, @m.edmondson so the documentation you quote isn't relevant, as I note in my edit in the answer. You're referencing a table that *does* exist and passing an invalid column name. A Column <> A Table.

Comment: This is genuinely surprising